# Dangers of splitting and reconnecting a ring circuit with oxidized aluminium wiring

Tags: electrical, circuit, aluminum-wiring

I'm in the UK, and have a ring circuit with old aluminium wiring.

I need to temporarily split and reconnect the ring at several sockets, in order to discover which part of the ring has a live-to-earth leakage fault (that is tripping the RCD). This will be done with all appliances unplugged, and therefore no load on the circuit (because the RCD trips even when nothing is plugged in - hence the conclusion that it must be a live-to-earth leak).

In each socket, there are obviously going to be two aluminium wires which have been twisted together and screwed into the socket. The aluminium wires will have probably oxidized.

Therefore, I'm worried that if I separate the wires, there will be a conductivity problem if I try and twist them together again to re-connect the ring.

Is this something I should be worried about? Is there a technique I should use to ensure the wires get reconnected to each other properly? In many sockets, I think I may have very limited cable lengths, and may have trouble finding enough slack to be able to simply cut off and strip back further cable.

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know aluminium had ever been legal in the UK.  My gut feeling is that you are going to get better answers from Americans than Brits - they may not have experience with working with ring circuits, but the principles aren't hard to learn, and the _do_ have experience of working with alumin[i]um.

Comment: Are you sure it's aluminium? AIUI while aluminium building wiring is not unheard of in the UK it's a lot less common than tinned copper.

Comment: @PeterGreen thanks for pointing that out - the emergency electrician simply looked at the colour of the wire going into the circuit breaker and told us it was aluminium. But maybe his assumption was wrong... I can see some copper glints on the wires I've pulled out of the sockets, but that could be the old brass screw fittings rubbing off on the wire. I tried scraping the wire with a knife, but it's really hard to tell if I'm seeing a slightly different colour or not. I can't see any informative markings on the cable. Any tips on how I can tell?

Comment: @PeterGreen Btw another electrician came today and confirmed it is definitely aluminium and not tinned copper. That would explain why I was not seeing a different colour after scraping the wire. He said it would be more of a yellowish silver outer colour if it were tinned copper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much space you have in the sockets, you might be best off cutting back to clean wire and inserting the ring ends into (eg) a Wago connector, and then running a <s>copper</s> aluminium pigtail (inside blue/brown/green+yellow insulation) to the socket.

**IMPORTANT**: If you do use a pigtail to connect to the socket, you need to make sure the socket is designed for the wire of the pigtail.  The current sockets are probably designed for aluminium, and may not accept copper.  OTOH, getting some more aluminium cable may be rather tricky - in which case you will need to use copper cable and change the sockets.

Alternatively, as above, except instead of cutting back, straighten out the wire, and clean up the end with very fine emery paper.

According to Wago (https://www.wago.com/gb/building-technology/electrical-installers/practical-tip-connecting-aluminum-and-copper-conductors) you need a special paste, and the right sort of Wago connector for this.

---

Alternatively, https://www.eca.co.uk/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?guid=119bf47a-e1d0-4fc8-a929-852746a1372b suggests crimping - you will need a proper crimp tool.

---

The final approach is to give up and rewire the house - that wiring is 50 years old now!

Comment: 50 years usually not a good reason to rewire a house, unless quite a few other problems with the wiring.

Comment: A live-to-earth leak is the sort of problem that would make me think about it though.  Also the presence of Al, which while it _can_ be installed safely, appears to be a lot less forgiving than Cu.

Comment: Thanks, the emery paper, Wago 222 and paste sounds good. Electricians I've asked have said they don't want to do a rewiring job if anyone is living in the house. It'd also be very expensive and disruptive to replace all old aluminium sockets and pull up floorboards and break through into walls. By narrowing the fault down to one section of the house, that'd mean we'd only have to disrupt one wall and one section of floorboards. Btw do you agree with the conclusion that if the RCD trips with no appliances connected, it must be a live-to-earth leak?

Comment: Depending on how the earthing is arranged, it could be a neutral-to-earth short too.  Modern housing usually has the earth bonded to the neutral where the power comes into the house, but you haven't got a modern installation, and if you are out in the sticks you might have neutral coming in with power, but earth provided by an earth spike.  In that case there can be 10's of volts difference between them - which is quite enough for an RCD trip.

Comment: Even with a TN-C-S installation it's quite possible for a neutral-earth fault to trip a RCD. Only a very small proportion of the current has to go the wrong way to trip a 30mA RCD.

Answer (score 1):

To remove oxidation, just polish them off with a Scotchbrite pad (synthetic "steel wool" used in kitchen sponges).  Do not use actual steel wool or you'll create the oxidation you're worried about.

I doubt they'll be that bad, though. Main thing: use terminals approved for aluminum wire and torque to spec with a torque measuring device.

You could rewire with copper, but copper is no more forgiving re: screw torques.

Comment: Whoa, thanks, I'm so glad you told me about the "actual steel wool" issue. Btw, do you happen to know whether there are any health risks related to the oxidization dust that is scoured off? Either from touching or breathing it? You're right, I've started to split the ring, and the aluminium wires do not appear to be in the awful condition that I had feared. I've narrowed it down to a region of the circuit under the floorboards where there is a 20kΩ live-to-earth resistance, so soon when the floorboards are pulled up I'll discover what is going wrong...

Comment: @AndrewParks You're soaking in it lol. Aluminum constitutes 8% of the earth's crust. It's everywhere. Even organic foods contain it.  While low resistance measurements from plain old ohmmeters do indicate a problem, high resistances are inconclusive. Many insulation failures don't occur at low test voltages and are only seen at high voltages. A special high-test-voltage ohmmeter called a "megger" is used for a conclusive test.

Comment: Yeah the steel wool thing is because aluminum is soft enough to catch steel dust from the wool. The steel suffers normal rusting Fe+O -> FeO.  Unfortunately, FeO+Al -> Fe+AlO is an exothermic reaction, so it happens. Thus degrading the aluminum.